# Is there a method for pull quotes?

Tags: themes, markdown, pelican

Is there an existing method for pull quotes with Pelican? When you're reading an article, and there are balloons with key sentence fragments or excerpts to highlight the area. Ideally, I want to write the text once, and just surround it with whatever delimeter is appropriate and have the template do its magic.

Answer (score 1):

An outdated plugin is available at https://github.com/arocks/markdown-pullquote. With a little tweaking - it works!